# Handle an android device shut down (ISSUE : The intent is received only the first time)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to handle an android device shut down : When the device is shutting down, a singleton, named `PostManager`, sends a POST request.

To do so, i'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
 public class DeviceOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {
            PostManager.getInstance().onDeviceOff();
        }
    }
}

public class PostManager{
        public void onDeviceOff() {
        sendRequest();
    }
}
```

Here is the `BroadcastReceiver` initialization :

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(".DeviceOffReceiver");
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN);
    mShutDownReceiver= new DeviceOffReceiver ();
    app.registerReceiver(mShutDownReceiver, filter);
```

This code works perfectly.. but only the first time. By "first time", I mean the first time the app is run.
Has anyone ever experienced the same issue ?

EDIT : I register the intent `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. I receive it every time. It has something to do with the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` intent.

Comment: Make sure you register the BroadcastReceiver again after reboot

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I do register the BroadcastReceiver at each reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My device version is 4.3.
I tried to run the app with another device (on 5.0.2) and it works every time...

So it has something to do with 4.3 (maybe ?).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put this code into Manifest.
You can use this code to solve issue:

```
<receiver android:name=".DeviceOffReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I did this programmatically.

Comment: Try it with defining in Manifest file. May be Receiver Leakage problem will be there.

Comment: As you Register Receiver grammatically then its Register and Unregister must be handled. As per my experience while you are dealing with OS Broadcasting we should go with Manifest.

Comment: I removed the initialization part and add your code in the manifest.. BUT i'm still having this issue :(